# Find in files does nothing

Tags: textpad

After the latest Windows 10 upgrade cleared all of my Textpad settings, I have been feeding them all back in again.

- However, Find in files now does nothing at all.
- The List option in the keyboard mapping setup also does nothing.
- Same for Compare Files.

I assume there is something wrong with the overall command output settings...

Where do these commands actually run?
Do they need a specific directory to use?
Are there settings I could check?

I have version 7.6.3

Comment: This is causing me all sorts of trouble. Has anybody got any ideas at all?

Comment: Fixed it -- although I have no idea how ...

* Closed Textpad
* renamed ConfigState.xml to saved-ConfigState.xml
* Opened Textpad
* Tools output still fails
* Closed Textpad
* renamed saved-ConfigState.xml back to ConfigState.xml
* Opened Textpad
* Tools output now works

Compared ConfigState.xml with an old one and no changes there imply anything. None of the configuration seems to have changed.

Having no config file must have "reset something", but that is hardly a valid diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

- Quit TextPad
- In the appdata directory, you have a `GUIState-xxxx.xml` file. Rename it to `GUIState-xxxx-saved.xml` or whatever you want.
- Launch Textpad
- Quit Textpad
- A brand new `GUIState-xxxx.xml` file should appear.
- Open it and look for the `<DockingPane>` node
- Copy in clipboard the `<Pane-4 ...>` about the "Find in files" entry
- Open your saved GUIState file and paste to replace the same entry in it.
- Delete the brand new file and rename back your saved file to its original name
- Launch Textpad

This should work ! (That's worked for me)